# CMake and Java: compile, not jar, for javah

Tags: java, java-native-interface, cmake

when using JNI, we would do the following on bash/cmd:

1. Compile the sources
2. Generate the headers
3. Build the native library
4. Zip the whole thing

In script, something like:

```
javac foo.java
javah foo
cmake . && make
jar .....
```

How can I reproduce on CMake?

Other than using CUSTOM_COMMAND I could only find add_jar to compile the java sources. Is it possible to compile the sources in CMake without jaring them afterwards?

Or should I resign and add_jar the java sources, build the library and add_jar again?

Also, how is Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE supposed to be used, with CUSTOM_COMMAND?

Answer (score 2):

I have a project where I'm trying to achieve something like this. (And some Android NDK work using android-cmake, with limited success, though that's not the point of your question.)

CMake does support options for building Java. [see note 1] However, that's exactly how it's oriented: your native code is the first-class citizen as far as this build system is concerned, so keep that in mind if you're considering going down the same road that I did. Some people use CMake as a *component* of their Java workflow, under ant/maven or things of that nature, and there [are various plugins](https://code.google.com/p/cmakeant/) that load CMake projects within the scope of a 'larger' build.

But I think this really thwarts the value of CMake's generators. I investigated doing that, but we ended up not going down that route. That's really a choice you'll have to make for yourself. (I find this project *has* Java, not ***is*** in Java, so it makes sense for me to do something more like what you're asking after.)

Here's the thing: add_jar has a little black-box magic to it. If you want to integrate UseJNI... well, I couldn't find much in the way of support for that. (Reading through the source of the module included in CMake 2.8.x exposes things like CMAKE_JNI_TARGET. Though I never really got that working, I [included it](https://github.com/hagemt/libalexandria/blob/master/bindings/java/CMakeLists.txt#L35) anyway. Here is my custom solution to this problem:

[Good stuff for your top-level CMakeLists.txt in projects that use Java](https://github.com/hagemt/libalexandria/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L108)

[Contains the definition of a helpful macro: javah](https://github.com/hagemt/libalexandria/blob/master/include/libalexandria/laJ/CMakeLists.txt)

[A sample of how to use the macro around native libraries](https://github.com/hagemt/libalexandria/blob/master/bindings/java/jni/CMakeLists.txt#L28)

[1] At the time of this writing, there appear to be two methods:

- via project(PROJECT_NAME Java) to notify CMake it needs to find a generic Java compiler
- find_package({Java, JNI}), which exposes a bit more functionality, including add_jar

[Here is reference for the later](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aFindJava) which I found myself referencing quite a bit.

Good luck.